# Get excel filename and path error - C#

Tags: c#, excel, vsto

I am getting a very stupid error. I am new to VSTO and I need to get the location of the Excel file in some variable in my Addin.

```
string name = ActiveWorkbook.FullName;
```

I am getting a red line below `ActiveWorkbook` with error:

```
The name ActiveWorkBook does not exist in the current context.
```

I have added reference of Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel in the code but its showing this error. I am new to this.. am I missing something?

Comment: I think it should Application.Something.ActiveWorkbook. Cant remember the exact name

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Excel VSTO, you need to use `Globals.ThisAddIn.Application` to get access to the Excel Application Model, see below :

```
   var wb = Globals.ThisAddIn.Application.ActiveWorkbook;
   string name = wb.FullName;
```

see also [Programming VSTO Add-ins](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/vsto/programming-vsto-add-ins)

If your code is inside the `ThisAddIn` class you can directly call: `this.Application.ActiveWorkbook`

Comment: Thank so much. I just find the right source to reference documents. Microsoft documentation is so much confusing. Thanks alot anyways. :)

Answer (score 0):

[`ActiveWorkbook`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.office.interop.excel._application.activeworkbook.aspx) is not a class. It's the property of the [`Application`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.office.interop.excel._application.aspx) interface. You can not call it in the class-name manner.

Then, you need to change your code to `this.Application.ActiveWorkbook.FullName;`

Comment: It's an add-in, so he probably already has an application instance. He just needs to use the property from that instance.